# How to hide PHP URLs and without reloading page?

Tags: php

I have two questions in mind to ask you guys here,
I'm working everyday with PHP scripts but I don't know very good javascript so my questions are:

I have script and for every navbar I'll click or button then page will refresh,
So can I get any method from you guys, how to show IMG LOADER instead reloading page?

Also per example: For button called "Update", in PHP I use /update.php?id=10 , Can I hide parameters just to be in URL: /update.php and to works like with parameter, and to show client IMG loader instead refreshing page/

Please, Just tell me methods which I can use to do them!

Comment: You should check out ajax (jquery) and post method of form

Comment: For `/update.php?id=10` you will need to look at `GET` and `POST` methods.  :)

Answer (score -3):

bro its very very easy through javascript, once just try to javascript.
you just copy paste this code, and result will showing as you want

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
     <!--
        function AutoRefresh( t ) {
           setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        }
     //-->
  </script>
```

This page will refresh every 5 seconds.

2nd, Answer of 2nd Question is, if use parameters, then try to routing,

Comment: What means "t" as by knowledgle of PHP, I tried with put URL into that but nothing. Hopefully you can help me again!